# Modification to heat map

Tags: r, graphics, heatmap

I am making a heat map though would like to separate the columns and add a line between each row. I am well aware that doing so makes this well, not a heat map. But this is how my boss envisions it.

Below is my code for the current heat map. Any advice on separating the columns & adding a line between each "person" would be much appreciated.

```
x11 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1) 
x22 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x <- rbind(x11, x22) 
hv <- heatmap(t(x), col = c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"), margins = c(4, 12), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "none", xlab ="", ylab ="", main = "",  labCol=c("BP", "Cx"), cexCol =2)
legend("topright", c("No Osteomyelitis", "Osteomyelitis"), col=c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"), bty="n", fill=c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"))
```

Yes I ended up using the code below. Thank you for the answer. I used gplots & got rid of the color key & histogram & added my own legend instead.

```
hv <- heatmap.2(t(x), key=FALSE, trace="none", colsep = seq(1,nrow(x)-1),
      rowsep = seq(1,ncol(x)-1),
      sepcolor = "white",
      sepwidth = c(0.1, 0.0005), col = c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"), margins = c(4, 12), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "none", xlab ="", ylab ="", main = "",  labCol=c("BP", "Cx"), cexCol =2)
legend("topleft", c("No Osteomyelitis", "Osteomyelitis"), col=c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"), bty="n", fill=c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you swap to `gplots::heatmap.2()` which allows greater control over plotting with mostly the same arguments.

Building on your good example (+1 btw) by adding the `colsep`, `rowsep`, `sepcolor` and `sepwidth` arguments to control the separation between the rows and columns (and `trace = 'none'` because I don't like it) gives:

```
x11 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1) 
x22 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x <- rbind(x11, x22) 
hv <- heatmap(t(x), col = c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"), margins = c(4, 12), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, scale = "none", xlab ="", ylab ="", main = "",  labCol=c("BP", "Cx"), cexCol =2)
legend("topright", c("No Osteomyelitis", "Osteomyelitis"), col=c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"), bty="n", fill=c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"))

library(gplots)
heatmap.2(t(x), 
      col = c("cornflowerblue", "hotpink"), 
      margins = c(4, 12), 
      Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, 
      scale = "none", 
      xlab ="", 
      ylab ="", 
      main = "",
      labCol=c("BP", "Cx"), 
      cexCol = 2,
      trace = 'none',
      colsep = seq(1,nrow(x)-1),
      rowsep = seq(1,ncol(x)-1),
      sepcolor = "white",
      sepwidth = c(0.1, 0.05))
```

[image: heatmap with separation]

To separate the columns more, increse the first element of `sepwidth` and similarly for the rows.

Comment: yes agreed, will share the code I ended up using. Thanks!